# ¿Como escribir datos en la DataBase de Firebase?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, firebase

**Hola, mundo!**

Mi problema actual es que no obtengo una respuesta al accionar mi método de escritura, aunque conozco que este método tarda algo en responder entre segundos y minutos, pero ya se excedió ya ha tardado entre 15 minutos en responder (y no responde), simplemente la consola se queda en run sin cargar nada referente al estado (coloco el código antes de los demás en mi clase Main).

**Método de iniciación de Firebase**

```
        public void CargarEstacionesPrueba() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\ABRAHAM-JOSE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BoxAdministrator\\gasmexico-firebase-adminsdk-kd815-2c786f5e18.json"));
    try{
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://gasmexico.firebaseio.com/")
         .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        // [END initialize]
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: invalid service account credentials. See README.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        EscribirListaPrueba("AP");

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FirebaseConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("si1");

    // Start listening to the Database


}
```

**Método de escritura**

```
        public void EscribirListaPrueba(String name) throws InterruptedException{
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("gasmexico");
        DatabaseReference postsRef = ref.child("post");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        DatabaseReference newPostRef = postsRef.push();

        // We can also chain the two calls together
        final CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);
        postsRef.push().setValue(name, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
              if (databaseError != null) {
               System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
              } else {
                System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                sync.countDown();
              }
            }
          });

           sync.await();


    }
```

**Manera en como llamo el método de iniciación desde la Class Main**

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new update_data().setVisible(true);
            FirebaseConexion fireConnec=new FirebaseConexion();
            try {
                fireConnec.CargarEstacionesPrueba();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    });



}
```

**Mi estructura de base de datos (el .json)**

```
  "post" : {
    "id" : {
      "nombre" : "abc"
    }
  }
```

Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.

Comment: para entender mejor el problema, no te esta cargando nada en la consola de Firebase o no te esta buscando los datos que escribiste en la consola dentro de tu codigo ?

Comment: En ambas no escribe en la base de Firebase y no procede la devolución, que le permitiría a mi código continuar libremente con lo siguiente a procesar. Gracias